# OpenMP for-loop chunk scheduling visualization

Tags: performance, parallel-processing, openmp, visualization

Are there tools that visualize execution of OpenMP for-loop chunks?
For example, consider the parallel for-loop below:

```
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic, 10) num_threads(4)
for(int i=1; i<100; i++)
{
    // do work of uneven execution time.
}
```

I want to visualize on which thread each of the 10 chunks (say (1,10),(11,20),...,(91,100)) executed and how long they took, without modifying code?

I understand that only four (one per thread) parallel outline functions are started, and that each of these functions ask for chunks in a synchronized manner. I can visualize the four parallel outline functions in tools such as Intel VTune, but am unable to drill this visualization down to the chunk level.

Thanks in advance for your tips and suggestions!